# CI3 (Twig) Query result array is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, codeigniter-3

I'm making a language system with CodeIgniter 3 and Twig. I store the phrases in my database with the fields `keyword`, `value` and `language`. My code to get the language data from the database is as follows:

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")
    ->get("phrases")
    ->result_array();

$this->twig->addGlobal("phrase", $query);
```

And if I `var_export($query)` it returns this:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '31', 'keyword' => 'hello_world', 'value' => 'Hello World', 'language' => 'english', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '35', 'keyword' => 'beautiful_weather', 'value' => 'It\'s a beautiful weather today', 'language' => 'english', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '36', 'keyword' => 'goodbye', 'value' => 'Goodbye!', 'language' => 'english', ), 3 => array ( 'id' => '37', 'keyword' => 'test', 'value' => 'Test123', 'language' => 'english', ), )
```

What I want to achieve with this is to be able to print the phrases into my twig template by using the keyword associated to the array above. Meaning if I print the following line into any Twig template file:

```
{{ phrase.hello_world }}
```

...it should automatically print the value of the field `hello_world` from my language table.

I experimented some on my own and tried to do the following...

```
foreach($query as $result)
{
    $this->twig->addGlobal("phrase." . $result->keyword, $result->value);
}
```

But due to the fact that twig thinks that a `.` next to a variable indicates reading from an array, it doesn't work. If I change the sign to for example `_` it works, but that looks messy in the template code (becaue keywords from the database also uses `_` and everything else looks really ugly), so I really need to use the `.`

Sidenote: **I do not want to use a foreach loop inside the twig template file.**

Comment: what's is the result `$query`? Does it have a `fieldname` key?

Comment: yes it does, but it seem to store each row in a new array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `->select("*")`. From [CodeIgniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html):

> #### `$this->db->select()`
>
> ...
>
> If you are selecting all (*) from a table you do not need to use this function. When omitted, CodeIgniter assumes that you wish to select all fields and automatically adds ‘SELECT *’.

So you can do just this:

```
$query = $this->db->get("phrases")->result_array();
```

By the way, I think that e.g. `$phrases` would be a better variable name.

[Another doc page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) describes the `result_array()` method:

> This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you’ll use this in a foreach loop.

So, `$query` is an array, so you need to loop through it in Twig. The array is not empty, you even posted its contents to your question. I expanded the contents to multiple rows for readability:

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => '31',
        'keyword' => 'hello_world',
        'value' => 'Hello World',
        'language' => 'english'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => '35',
        'keyword' => 'beautiful_weather',
        'value' => 'It\'s a beautiful weather today',
        'language' => 'english'
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => '36',
        'keyword' => 'goodbye',
        'value' => 'Goodbye!',
        'language' => 'english'
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => '37',
        'keyword' => 'test',
        'value' => 'Test123',
        'language' => 'english'
    ]
]
```

So, you have four items and each of them has keys `id`, `keyword`, `value` and `language`. You can loop through the array in Twig e.g. like this:

```
{% for item in query %}
    ID is {{ item.id }}
    Keyword is {{ item.keyword }}
    Value is {{ item.value }}
    Language is {{ item.language }}

{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
ID is 31
Keyword is hello_world
Value is Hello World
Language is english

ID is 35
Keyword is beautiful_weather
Value is It&#039;s a beautiful weather today
Language is english

ID is 36
Keyword is goodbye
Value is Goodbye!
Language is english

ID is 37
Keyword is test
Value is Test123
Language is english
```

*Edit:*

You can perform the `foreach` loop in PHP like this:

```
$phrase = [];

foreach ($query as $result) {
    $phrase[$result->keyword] = $result->value;
}

$this->twig->addGlobal("phrase", $phrase);
```

And then in Twig:

```
{{ phrase.hello_world }}
{{ phrase.beautiful_weather }}
{{ phrase.goodbye }}
{{ phrase.test }}
```

Comment: Good explanation, but as it's for a language system I don't want to use any loops in twig to use the variables. Is there any way to do that directly in the PHP so this can be achieved? (All my attempts so far have failed.)

Comment: @P.Nick What do you specifically want to do? Can you update your question with more details?

Comment: Updated, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @P.Nick Happy to help! :)